# Windows Phone/XNA detecting BEGINNING of touch

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xna, touch, windows-phone

I want to make buttons change color upon a touch in windows Phone, but the only available gesture is `GestureType.Tap` which is called after a tap is complete, so the color changes after the user touches the button. How do I make a touch detected as soon as it is touched?

```
        while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
        {

            GestureSample gs = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
            switch (gs.GestureType)
            {
               //this is called AFTER the tap
               case GestureType.Tap:
                    if (Restart.tapped(gs.Position))
                        Restart.selectDrawColor = Color.OrangeRed;
                    else
                        Restart.selectDrawColor = Color.White;

                    if (uploadScore.tapped(gs.Position))
                        uploadScore.selectDrawColor = Color.OrangeRed;
                    else
                        uploadScore.selectDrawColor = Color.White;

                    if (MainMenu.tapped(gs.Position))
                        MainMenu.selectDrawColor = Color.OrangeRed;
                    else
                        MainMenu.selectDrawColor = Color.White;
                    break;
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Touching the screen is not considered a gesture, so `ReadGesture` will not return it. You will need to call [`TouchPanel.GetState()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.touch.touchpanel.getstate.aspx) and look for any `TouchLocation` objects that have a `State` of `Pressed`.

```
// using System.Linq;

TouchLocation[] newTouchLocations = TouchPanel.GetState()
    .Where(loc => loc.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
    .ToList();
```

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.input.touch.touchlocationstate.aspx), `TouchLocationState.Pressed` signifies:

> This touch location position is new.

Comment: Back in the day on the Zune HD this was all we had to use to read touch input... And we liked it!

Comment: In the code snippet the Array is getting filled with a Generic List. Shouldn't it be `.ToArray()` instead of `.ToList()` here?